# aliases for external containers linked through network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Lets say we have two web services: alpha & beta

1) `docker-compose.yml` for **alpha**:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        env_file: local.env
        networks:
          - default
          - beta

    networks:
        beta:
            external:
                name: beta_default
```

2) `docker-compose.yml` for **beta**:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        env_file: .env
        expose:
          - "5000"
```

That way I can interact (e.g ping) `beta_web_1` container from `alpha_web_1` container. What I want is to make an alias for `beta_web_1` container, so that I could name it after a valid URL, e.g: `beta.local`.

I would like this to happen inside `docker-compose.yml` for `alpha` or in any way that keeps it inside alpha's scope of view, so that I wouldn't need to change the actual system-wide name for `beta_web_1`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had missed that there is an `aliases` options under `networks`. That way if we change the `docker-compose.yml` files to:

1) alpha/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        env_file: local.env
        networks:
          default:
             aliases:
                - alpha.local
          beta:

networks:
    beta:
        external:
            name: beta_default
```

2) beta/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        env_file: .env
        expose:
          - "5000"
        networks:
          default:
             aliases:
                - beta.local
          alpha:

networks:
    alpha:
       external:
            name: alpha_default
```

Now we can ping `beta.local` container from alpha and `alpha.local` container from beta.

Comment: is it possible to do the samething for external endpoints? for e.g. if I want alpha to reach to an external ip (API end point) can I define an alias for that ip in the compose file?

Comment: @tkyass If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is `extra_hosts` https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for .. thanks @chefarov

Comment: this is brilliant!!